Numeric coefficients of a series/polynomial
In my work, i usually come across expressions of the form: $$\text{L3}=\frac{625 f_5^{30} q^4}{f_1^{31}}+\frac{24458 f_5^{24} q^3}{f_1^{25}}+\frac{25436 f_5^{18} q^2}{f_1^{19}}+\frac{25415 f_5^{12} q}{f_1^{13}}+\frac{125 f_5^6}{f_1^7}.$$ I would like to extract only numeric coefficients of the above expression L3 i.e., i should get {625,24458,25436,25415,125} as a list in Mathematica. If we use CoefficientList[], we get all the coefficients along with f_i's as well. Tried with ChatGPT another command: coefficients=Cases[L3,_?NumericQ,Infinity], but this also not working as this gives subscripts and superscripts of $f_i$'s in list How can i get only numeric coefficients in Mathematica?
L3=(125 Subsuperscript[f, 5, 6])/Subsuperscript[f, 1, 7]+(25415 q Subsuperscript[f, 5, 12])/Subsuperscript[f, 1, 13]+(25436 q^2 Subsuperscript[f, 5, 18])/Subsuperscript[f, 1, 19]+(24458 q^3 Subsuperscript[f, 5, 24])/Subsuperscript[f, 1, 25]+(625 q^4 Subsuperscript[f, 5, 30])/Subsuperscript[f, 1, 31]
CoefficientList[L3,q]
coefficients=Cases[L3,_?NumericQ,Infinity]

Any other way to get only numeric coefficients when we have a polynomial containing variable coefficients as well.

I think you can just replace the unwanted coefficients with 1s.  For example, CoefficientList[L3, q] /. _Subsuperscript -> 1

data = Cases[L3, c_?NumericQ*v_ :> v -> c]; Values[data]? The point of data is that Plus is Orderless, and you might need to know which coefficient goes with which term.

Change Plus to List using Apply. Then set all variables to one using ReplaceAll.
